# How can I stress test my system?

Tags: cpu, hardware-failure

Apologies if this is a beginner question.

I've just 'successfully' built a gaming PC myself, and everything works perfectly, apart from one thing. I keep getting this error when trying to sync my bitcoin wallet.

[image: sync bitcoin wallet error]

I've tried everything under the sun to get this working, different versions of the wallet, clean installs, but no, without fail, the database keeps getting corrupted. I saw on a forum that bad math from an overheated or overclocked processor can be a cause this error.

Is this true? Each of my cores are averaging 40 degrees Celsius, which I know is fine. I haven't even attempted overclocking.

Could the error be caused by bad hardware? Somewhat easier to understand is the fact that the error could be caused by bad sectors on my SSD. Or bad RAM addresses. How can I find out if hardware is faulty? Are there clues that I can do right now, or should I find a program to stress test?

Comment: If you're getting DB errors, and not explicit crashing of the application (or something indicating another type of error), I would assume this is indicative of a *possible* sector fault with the storage drive.  I would check your filesystem and the sectors on the drive throughly (or run your SSD through a health-check utility; many manufacturers provide one, and there are also generic utilities available).  If you had some bad RAM (or a bad CPU), I would *expect* you to experience more generic system crashes or BSODs.  **Don't rule these things out, but I'd start my diagnosis on the SSD**.

Comment: Actually thinking further, it depends how the database would be implemented, although I am assuming it has to be periodically purged to disk (which would be the likely point of failure here).  That being said, as I mentioned, I would not rule out RAM (you can test it with Memtest86+) or your CPU (you can test it with Prime95).

Comment: @Breakthrough Darn...tested with Samsung Magician and Windows' drive tester. Seems fine.

Still think RAM / CPU could cause this error? I've yet to experience a crash (computer has probably had around 78 hours uptime) and everything else on my computer is working perfectly?

Comment: Certainly.  If you have NOT ever tested your CPU/RAM before, you should do so ASAP. I always test my new computer builds with Memtest/Prime95, because even if a single bit flips in your entire computer's memory, that's not proper functionality.  Indeed, system crashes are likely if a lot of your RAM (or several CPU instructions don't work as intended), but that's the computer's *job* (to **stop** as soon as a hardware fault is detected, since using *wrong* values can be a lot worse than just halting).  However, small errors can sometimes cause no repeatable issues (outside of benchmarking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs like Prime95, PassMark's BurnInTest etc. can be used to torture-test or stress-test your CPU and other PC sub-systems. Your HDD/SSD manufacturer should provide a testing utility. MemTest86/MemTest86+ can be used to test your RAM, preferably one stick at a time. Obviously take care not to destroy your hardware by putting it under too much stress!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stress test, [this guy](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/100352-hardware-stress-test-prime95.html) recommends Prime95 to "Test your Hardware for Stability and Heat Problems"

FYI, make sure to notice his tip:

> Be sure to keep an eye on your temperatures when running these tests,
>   especially the Large FFTs. I recommend the free utility Speedfan.